# Kotlin - Wait function

Tags: kotlin, wait

**Is there a wait function in kotlin?** (I don't mean a Timer Schedule, but actually pause the execution). I have read that you can use `Thread.sleep()`. However, it doesn't work for me, because the function can't be found.

Comment: Sleep is always available, because it is part of the standard JDK. You just didn't call it with the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Thread sleep always takes a time how long to wait:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)

```
public static void sleep(long millis)
                  throws InterruptedException
```

e.g.

```
Thread.sleep(1_000)  // wait for 1 second
```

---

If you want to wait for some other Thread to wake you, maybe `Object#wait()' would be better

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()

```
public final void wait()
                throws InterruptedException
```

Then another thread has to call `yourObject#notifyAll()`

e.g.
Thread1 and Thread2 shares an `Object o = new Object()`

```
Thread1: o.wait()      // sleeps until interrupted or notified
Thread2: o.notifyAll() // wake up ALL waiting Threads of object o
```

Comment: Or just use `notify` if there is only one other thread that can lock the same object.

Answer (score 70):

Please try this, it will work for Android:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
    {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
    },
    1000 // value in milliseconds
)
```

Comment: Deprecated — use: 
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
    // Your Code
}, 1000)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo. Unless the original question was to hang the entire Thread, though "*pausing execution*" and sleeping threads are usually expressed similarly when explaining, in reality are not what the user needs.

Comment: @MariosYiannakou No, This answer is specific to Android but OP is asking generally how to wait in Kotlin.

Comment: The question is not tagged with "android", so why assume that android is the platform?

Answer (score 41):

Since new coroutines feature became available in Kotlin version 1.1 you can use *non-blocking* `delay` function with such signature:

`suspend fun delay(time: Long, unit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`

In Kotlin 1.2 it is still located in `kotlinx.coroutines.experimental` package. Experimental status of coroutines is described [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html#experimental-status-of-coroutines).

**UPD:** Kotlin 1.3 was released, coroutines were moved to `kotlinx.coroutines` package, they are no longer experimental feature.

**UPD 2:** To use this method inside non-suspendable methods it's possible to make it blocking, like any other suspendable methods, by surrounding with [`runBlocking {}`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines/coroutines-basic-jvm.html#my-first-coroutine):

```
runBlocking {
    delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
```

Comment: delay no longer takes a TimeUnit parameter.

Answer (score 27):

You can achieve this easily with Kotlin coroutines

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            delay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3))
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                Log.i("TAG", "this will be called after 3 seconds")
                finish()
            }
        }
        Log.i("TAG", "this will be called immediately")
    }
}
```

**build.gradle(app)**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: not only best written - it complies with google demands of using coroutines instead of handlers and threads on our own!

Answer (score 25):

You can use stuff of the standard JDK.

Another response suggests `Thread.sleep(millis: Long)`. Personally I prefer the TimeUnit class (since Java 1.5) which provides a more comprehensive syntax.

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1L)
TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(1000_000L)
```

They use `Thread.sleep` behind the scene, and they can throw InterruptedException too. Unfortunately, as pointed by @AndroidDev in a comment, they do not cooperate with Kotlin coroutines (since Kotlin 1.1). So we should prefer `delay` function in this context.

```
public suspend fun delay(timeMillis: Long): Unit
public suspend fun delay(duration: Duration): Unit
```

Comment: Don't use anything that uses sleep (such as Thread.sleep) inside a coroutine (suspend function). Kotlin will complain about it with "inappropriate thread-blocking method call'.

Answer (score 4):

you can use to wait or sleep for 2 seconds

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2L)
```

- 

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((seconds you want to sleep) + L)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve functionality using Mutex class in kotlin. '.lock()' and '.unlock()' are the methods were similar to wait and notify in java.

Answer (score 0):

According to kotlin docs: [wait()/notify()](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#wait-notify), you can simply convert an `Any` into an `Object` ***if you really want to*** rely on the native mechanism:

```kotlin
// The `Any` aka. `Object` in Java accessed by multiple threads.
val sharedList: List<Any> = ArrayList()

... ...

// One thread accessing the `Any`
synchronized(sharedList) {
    while(needWait) {
        try {
            // Convert it to `Object` and wait, thus release the lock.
            (sharedList as java.lang.Object).wait()
        } catch(_: InterruptedException) {}
    }
}
```

You can also wrap it as an extended function:

```kotlin
private fun Any.wait() = (this as java.lang.Object).wait()
private fun Any.notify() = (this as java.lang.Object).notify()

// Then you can use it as what you do in Java
synchronized(lock) {
    try {
        lock.wait()        // extended function
    } catch(_: InterruptedException) {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
SystemClock.sleep(1000)
```

Comment: That's an Android thing

Comment: `SystemClock.sleep()` doesn't throw InterruptedException; Thread.interrupt(), better than using `Thread.sleep()`