# How to set delay in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I just want to wait 2 or 3 seconds, I know how to do it in Java and I tried it, but no idea about kotlin

something simple like:

```
println("hello")
// a 2 seconds delay
println("world")
```

Comment: What did you try? And what happened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin - Wait function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213706/kotlin-wait-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*****there are some ways:*****

**1- use Handler(base on mili-second)(Deprecated):**

```
println("hello")
Handler().postDelayed({
   println("world")
}, 2000)
```

**2- **by using Executors(base on second):****

```
println("hello")
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule({
    println("world")
}, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

**3- by using Timer(base on mili-second):**

```
println("hello")
Timer().schedule(2000) {
  println("world")
}
```

Answer (score 14):

It's simple. Just use a coroutine. Like this:

```
fun main() = runBlocking { 
    launch { 
        delay(2000L)
        println("World!") 
    }
    println("Hello")
}
```

Don't forget to import kotlin coroutine like this:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
```

*Happy coding in kotlin!!!*

Comment: Why would you want to run this blocking? What would happen if the delay is bigger and in the meantime you exit the app?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
viewmodelScope.launch {
    println("hello")
    delay(2000)
    println("world")
}
```

Comment: If the apps goes to the background while your delay is running println("world") will run anyways, is that what you want?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use any dependencies then you can use `Thread.sleep(2000L)`
Here, 1 second = 1000L
The code should look like this,

```
println("hello")
Thread.sleep(2000L)
println("world")
```